# Youtube player not firing onReady and onStateChange event in IE 8 and IE 10

Tags: events, youtube

I've spent 3 solid days trying to resolve this issue. Very quickly, the Youtube player does not fire the onReady and onStateChange event in both IE8 and IE10. I tested it on Firefox and it works. Basically, I am developing a Windows 8 metro app that uses WebView to host the html, but it also doesnt work in WebView.

The video loads and the onYouTubeIframeAPIReady is called but that's about it. Below is the html code.

The alert message in onPlayerReady and onPlayerStateChange functions doesnt get displayed in IE8 and IE10 but is displayed in Firefox.

Please help.....

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body> 
<div id="player"></div> 
<script> 

alert('LOADING');
alert(GetUserAgent());

var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() 
{ player = new YT.Player('player', { height: '315', width: '560',
 videoId: 'CreKbwMTZA8', playerVars: {'autoplay': 1}, 
events: { 'onReady': onPlayerReady, 'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange }  });  
alert('onYouTubeIframeAPIReady');
}

function onPlayerReady(event) 
{ 
event.target.playVideo(); 
alert('onPlayerReady');
}

function onPlayerStateChange(event) 
{
alert('onPlayerStateChange');

if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) { window.external.notify('PLAYING');}
else if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {window.external.notify('ENDED');}
}

function setSize(width, height) 
{ player.setSize(width, height); 
}

function GetUserAgent() 
{
  return navigator.userAgent;
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```